# FortiClient SSL VPN Connected but cannot access IP

Tags: 12.04, networking, vpn

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit system. When I try to connect to VPN using forticlientsslvpn, it connects, but I cannot access the IP. I tried many solutions and couldnt find anything useful/working.

I am using http://kb.cloud.it/files/tar-gz/forticlientsslvpn_linux_4-0-2281-tar.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue was due to the same IP ranges, both my local network and VPN used `192.168.1.0` subnet.
I have changed my local IP range to `192.168.10.0` and added a route entry for vpn

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev ppp0
```

Then I could successfully access the vpn on `192.168.1.0`

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles on this in future:

On Ubuntu 18.04, the `route` command is no longer available by default, the equivalent with `ip` command would be 

`sudo ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev ppp0`

Comment: Also as a sidenote: 
https://hadler.me/linux/openfortigui/
Works well for newer Linux Versions instead of the forticlient which depends upon `netstat` and `route` commands